# QtWebkit rendering non-standard font, italic and normal switched

Tags: css, qt, fonts, qtwebkit

I am trying to use custom fonts in QtWebkit via @font-face, and it is not working properly only on Windows.

here is a sample of my code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBoldItalic';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoItalic';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}    
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBold';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


body{
    font-family: "Lato";
}
h1{
    font-family: 'LatoBold';
}
h2{
    font-family: 'LatoItalic';
}
```

So, my content and h1 should be in normal Lato, and only my h2 in Italic.

It does work on Mac Os, but italic and normal font are switched on Windows. I tried several things, by removing all Italic fonts (even from the filesystem), but text is style rendered in Italic...

I also tried to declare only one Lato font, and call a different .ttf for each weight and style, but I have the same problem.

Also tried with Lato font loaded from a website, same problem.

I don't really understand what is the problem here.

More information that should be helpful :

- Windows 7
- Qt 5.3.1
- Files are loaded from the filesystem, not online (file://.....)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a problem of the QT (Note: modern browsers often use `woff`)

You added `font-style: italic;` in `@font-face`, this requires in Webkit/Chrome added `font-style: italic;` in your selector also.

Example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoItalic';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Light-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'LatoItalic';
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Note: `woff` is used in modern browsers: Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+
Note: Try use moderns formats (and alternatives), see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked well. I assumed it was linked to Qt since I didn't have the problem in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: In my chrome have this problem (Windows 7 64bit). Good luck!